# How to convert string json to python float and back to number in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to solve a problem. I have a json list of products, ex:

```
[{
    "id": 5677240,
    "name": "Cønjuntø de Pænelæs æntiæderentes ¢øm 05 Peçæs Pæris",
    "quantity": 21,
    "price": "192.84",
    "category": "Panelas"
  },

  {
    "id": 9628920,
    "name": "Lava & Seca 10,2 Kg Sæmsung E¢ø ßußßle ßræn¢æ ¢øm 09 Prøgræmæs de Lævægem",
    "quantity": 57,
    "price": 3719.70,
    "category": "Eletrodomésticos"
  }]
```

But I basically need the "price" to be float like the second product. I have a large list of these products

(Ignore the weird characters I managed to fix it with help from a teacher.) I converted them to python object using this

```
import json

with open('br2.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
for product in data:
    product["price"] = product["price"].replace(",", "")
```

I want to replace the values that are in string with the "" to float

thanks in advance sorry I'm new to python so I don't understand much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string to float with `float()`. So instead of your `replace` line, try:

```
product['price'] = float(product['price'])
```